# Is the slope from differentiation formula different from actual tangent slope?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

As we know that tangent is the rate of change of a function and by the definition of a tangent on a curve, we know that it touches the curve at a single point but by the formula of differentiation, we find two points on the curve and try to minimize the difference between them but still we have the slope touching at least two points.

In a graphical representation:
[image: Actual and formulated slope in close-up]

- *Text in the image:*

  - **h->0**
  - **The actual slope** *(of the tangent)*
  - **The formulated slope** *(i.e. according to the definition of the differential)*

Comment: This is still not the case. Differentiation gives you the slope of the tangent (whih is the *limit* of the slopes of secants)

Comment: The tangent to a curve at a point is a line whose slope agrees with the slope (derivative)  at that point.  This may allow the tangent line to intersect the curve at some other point.  It isn't clear to me what your Question is.

Comment: "but we still have the slope touching at least two points" The derivative is a *limit* of slopes of secant lines. We are taking a limit.

Comment: The tangent line is the _limit_ of the corresponding set of secant lines. The tangent line is not itself a member of that set.

Comment: No, the definition of the tangent does _not_ say that it touches the curve at a single point. Not that I see how that matters - what are you asking, exactly?

Comment: We do not _try to minimise the difference_ between the two endpoints, but rather look for a limit as the endpoints approach the point at which we want the differential. _Trying to minimise the difference_ makes no sense, as on the one hand we can make the difference 0 (minimal) by taking the endpoints identical and on the other hand we can always reduce the difference if they are not identical.

Comment: Your diagram appears to be meant to illustrate that as long as the endpoints differ, the line through them will not be the tangent, however close they come to the point of evaluation. This is not true (think of a wavy line) and not relevant, because we are concerned with the limiting behaviour, not with the behaviour of some approximation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no. [The definition of *tangent to a curve at a point on the curve* in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent) (for the case where the curve is the graph of a function $ f $) says it is a line through that point with the same slope as the curve at that point, and the slope is defined as the differential. I.e. the slope of the tangent is by definition the result of differentiation.

The first illustration in that Wikipedia article also shows a tangent passing through another point on the curve, refuting your claim that the tangent only passes through one point on the curve.

A longer and perhaps more useful answer would help you to understand the misconceptions implicit in your question, but that is harder to supply, as your reasoning is not altogether clear. *To be extended: I shall try to assemble a fuller answer when I have a little more time*